# github linking with other repos

Tags: git, github, gitorious

I have a project that relies on two repos in github to function. 
When I submit my project to github how do I link to these two repos? 
Should I duplicate the files in my own repo or link to the other repo at a specific revision as I don't want it to update and cause incompatibility.
I already created my github repo what should I do?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use git submodules to "link" to other projects.

See here - https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/

Comment: What if my project has nothing to do to contribute towards the original repo I depend on? For instance I'm using an XML parser for my script but it's not nothing to do to contribute towards that project, should I still use submodules?

Comment: @user391986 Yes, it is not just about contributing to the other project.

Comment: last question when you update files inside that submodule if you push changes does it update my or the linked repo?

Comment: @user391986 - You said you are not contributing to it. If you push, it will (try to) update the linked repo.

Answer (score 20):

There is an alternative to submodules that I found out to be more practical: [**subtree**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).

According to this [link](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) the advantages are:

> - Management of a simple workflow is easy.
> - Older version of git are supported (even before v1.5.2).
> - The sub-project’s code is available right after the clone of the super project is done.
> - subtree does not require users of your repository to learn anything new, they can ignore the fact that you are using subtree to manage dependencies.
> - subtree does not add new metadata files like submodules doe (i.e. .gitmodule).
> - Contents of the module can be modified without having a separate repository copy of the dependency somewhere else.

Answer (score 20):

GitHub will also allow you to reference another repository in a comment on GitHub or in a commit. For example:

```
We should probably handle this with github/enterprise#59
```

This will add an update to the issue `github/enterprise#59` with a link to your comment/commit.

> ### Cross-Repository Issue References
>
> [image]
>
> Sure, GitHub's all about social coding, but you can have social repositories, too. You can reference issues between repositories by mentioning **user/repository#number** in an issue. Once we see something like that — say, github/enterprise#59 — we'll make sure to update issue #59 in github's enterprise repository and let you know where it was referenced from. This is a part of [GitHub Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/), which also has a few tricks of its own.

Read more: https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets

Comment: Does this also work for private repos? Some early tests show maybe not, even from within the same organization.