# Github Symlink a folder from a different directory

Tags: git, github

Think the title says it all. I need to be able to have a folder in my repo that is symlinked to a different repo that I do not own.

This way the my copy of it will stay up to date with the main repos.

Do I have to make my own fork of the main repo or can I just use the main repos master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible as far as git and github are concerned :)

Look at the answers for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357442/github-linking-with-other-repos) and you will have a decent set of "alternative" ways of doing what you want to do :)

To sum it up : you can go for [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [subtrees](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).

Comment: Ah alright, thanks for the heads up. I'll look into those two. Thanks