# How to link two repositories on Github?

Tags: git, github

I have a repository Named as "R1". This repository contain 4 Projects (P1,P2,P3 and P4).

I want to Link P1 with another repository R2 same P2 with R3. If I push the code on Repository R1 then it should be push for all linked repositories(R2 and R3).

Please suggest me if this is possible using GitHub.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357442/github-linking-with-other-repos thid may help

Answer (score 1):

There is no "automatic sync" between repo in Git or GitHub.

One possible implementation is:

- make sure `P1` or `P2` are in their own git repo (pushed to their respective GitHub repo)
- declare `P1` and `P2` as submodule of `R1`, [with a directive for them to follow a branch (like master)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)

  ```
  git submodule add -b master [URL of P1] P1/
  ```

That means, when you push anything in `P1` or `P2`, or all you need to do in `R1` or `R2` is:

```
git submodule update --remote
git add .
git commit -m "new SHA1 for P1 or P2"
git push
```

`R1` only monitors [gitlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entries in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) for `P1` or `P2`.

However that means more repos that you currently have: you had `R1` and `R2`, you would need `P1` and `P2` as repos as well.