# Linking offline local git repo to github

Tags: git

I'm starting a new project and I want to open source a segment of my repository.
but the other half I want to keep private.

The problem I am facing is I want my local repository to be the master and self contained as there are times my internet fails.

But i would like to have a subdirectory in my project to be public on github and for this part to be kept in sync with my local copy and github.

Is there a way I can go about doing this?

I've stumbled across this thread:
[github linking with other repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357442/github-linking-with-other-repos)
and I'm not quite sure if a subtree or submodule will do what i want.

Thanks

Comment: Only push the public parts and add the other stuff to your gitignore.

Comment: We use `submodules` the problem is that it is recommended run frequently the two following command to keep the repo consistent: `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with subtree:

git subtree add --prefix Public {my github repo} master